Rocky Linux 8.6: Why can't the system find the Python installation?
I have Python 3.6 and Python 3.10 installed in my server. I have five virtual servers and I would like to create a standalone 3.10 environment for one of them (I wouldn’t mind installing 3.11), but if I write
python -m venv miapi-env

the system returns me
-bash: python: command not found

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
if I write
whereis python

I get the answer:
python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-config /usr/local/lib/python3.10 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

I previously ran
sudo update-alternatives --config python3

with the following result:
There are 2 programs which provide 'python3'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/bin/python3.6
 + 2           /usr/bin/python3.10

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

(I selected number 2.)

System installations usually use python3 as the name of a Python 3 interpreter. Virtual environments tend to use python as the link name regardless of the version (as the version is fixed and implied by the version used to create the virtual environment in the first place).

I.e., python3.10 -m venv miami-envwill create a Python-3.10-based virtual environment inside of which you can use python as the name of the interpreter.

whereis is not actually a particularly useful command in this context. You want to check command -v python and/or examine your PATH.

Thanks to everyone, and especially to chepner. I have created the virtual environment. It is important to activate it afterwards: in the created directory itself: source bin/activate Now it works well.
